# How to add a PayPal Express Checkout button to cart or order_information pages

Tags: 8, commerce

I don't see that it's possible to have a "PayPal Express Checkout" button in commerce 2.x using commerce_paypal (out-of-the-box at least).  Even if using Express Checkout, the customer still needs to select it from the "order_information" screen, complete billing info, and then

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Correct, there is no code for this use case yet. You'd have to write it yourself. Would be happy to review a patch!